# how to use increment function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

**i am using DB to store values in database.**

**i have "course fees" column i what to "increment"  the "course_fees" value in column.**

**for example**

```
 DB::table('student')->where('registration_id','=', $request->registration_id)->increment(['course_fees' =>$request->course_fees]);
```

**this code increment the inserted value**

**how can i modified below code for increment "course_fees" value  like above**

```
      DB::table('student')->where('registration_id','=', $request->registration_id)->update(['payment_date' => $request->payment_date,'balance_fees' => $request->balance_fees,'course_fees' =>$request->course_fees]);
```

Comment: Are you trying to increment all 3 fields by the amounts passed in the request?

Comment: @Rwd I want to increment just  "course_fees" column only

Comment: I have added an answer to the question, however, Marcins's answer already included this. I have just expanded on the parameters that `increment()`/`decrement()` take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`increment()`/`decrement()` can take 3 parameters: `$column, $amount, $extra`.

`$column` is the field that you want to increment
`$amount` is by how much you want to increment the field by
`$extra` is an array of attributes that you also want to update in the query.

If you don't pass an amount the default for `$amount` is 1.

---

To achieve what you're after you could do:

```
DB::table('student')
    ->where('registration_id', $request->registration_id)
    ->increment('course_fees', $request->course_fees, [
        'payment_date' => $request->payment_date,
        'balance_fees' => $request->balance_fees,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use this method to increment multiple fields. You can use:

```
$studentQuery = DB::table('student')->where('registration_id','=', $request->registration_id);

(clone $studentQuery)->increment('payment_date',$request->payment_date);
(clone $studentQuery)->increment('balance_fees', $request->balance_fees);
(clone $studentQuery)->increment('course_fees', $request->course_fees);
```

but this way you will run 3 database queries to update.

But if you are sure there is exactly single record found for registration_id you can do it like this:

```
$student = DB::table('student')->where('registration_id','=', $request->registration_id)->first();

$student->update([
   'payment_date' => $student->payment_date + $request->payment_date,
   'balance_fees' => $student->balance_fees + $request->balance_fees,
   'course_fees' => $student->course_fees + $request->course_fees
]);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to increment only `course_fees` column and want to update other 2 columns from input you can use:

```
DB::table('student')->where('registration_id','=', $request->registration_id)
->increment('course_fees' , $request->course_fees, [
   'payment_date' => $request->payment_date,
   'balance_fees' => $request->balance_fees
])
```

This is [documentation about increment/decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#increment-and-decrement) methods.

Comment: @user12380208 So why in your code there are 3 columns? You want to only increment this column or maybe also update other fields? Hard to tell from your question

Comment: i am just updating,this two columns( payment_date, balance_fees ) and i am increment  "course_fees" column only

Comment: @user12380208 Please take a look at my updated answer